# Totals without showing each contact in Contact related reports

Tags: civireport, reports

Is it possible to have contact reports with listings that do not initially show each contact as a row but displays only the totals for the sorting groups?  I have thousands of contacts and want to have a report that shows how many contacts are within each postal code or totals for each gender, etc.  I know we can get the totals to be displayed using the Sort area and clicking the check box for "Section Header / Group By".  However, my results have hundreds of pages and I just want to see the totals for each category.

We are currently on CiviCRM 4.6.20.0 on Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

one way to do this would be to use the Aggregation feature in Drupal Views. This can be set to give you a 'count' for any of the fields in the row, so you could have your postcode in one column and a 'count' of the 'contact IDs' in the next. You would then be able to make the 'postcode' function as a link so that you could then click through to see all the contacts in that postcode.

Of course it really depends what you want to 'do' with that data after you see it. But if reporting the numbers is the primary goal, this may work for you.

Expect others to provide a 'how to' using Reports directly.